# Non-ASCII Characters displayed but cannot encode with platform encoding

Tags: java, xml-parsing, vaadin7, non-ascii-characters, windows-1252

I have a vaadin 7 application and when we enter multi byte character such as ÆÇË these values displayed correctly. the encoding set in setenv.sh file as Windows-1252(exported as a jvm option). but when a XML string with above characters converted to XML as follows.

```
`byte[] xmlRawData = string.trim().getBytes((Charset.defaultCharset());// char set is Windows-1252

Element element = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlRawData))`
```

An error message shown as follows

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 41; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Can you please explain this, why utf-8 even after the default encoding is Windows-1252? How to convert this

Comment: Does your UI also use cp 1252? Note that unless you're converting from string to byte and vice versa the encoding doesn't matter and I'd assume Vaadin has its own coding set (very likely it usesUTF-8).

Comment: Problem is UI is using windows-1252. but what the encoding in the header of xml string is utf-8. any way to overcome this?

Comment: You could try to wrap your byte stream with an `InputSource` and set the encoding there.

Comment: Btw, is there a reason to prefer cp 1252 over utf-8? The only one I could think of is size with utf-8 requiring some more space for non-ascii characters but nowadays this should hardly matter.